# Find the neighbouring polygons of a given polygon in a MySQL spatial table in ver < 5.6.1

Tags: mysql, spatial

**Finding neighbouring shapes in MySQL spatial table made up of ID and 2D geometry (polygon) fields.**

I have a table with an `ID column` and a `geometry column` (holding a `polygon`) representing various areas on a map. Given the ID of a particular row, say `ID 4`, I would like to find every polygon in the table that `meets/touches` the `polygon held at ID 4`.

I am aware MySQL < 5.6.1 only uses Minimum bounding rectangle rather than a proper function for this so could accept any MBR of another geometry column that intersects it for example.

I am having a little difficulty starting to write such a query. It would go something along the lines of:

```
check all rows for MBR_Intersects(some geometry column, geometry column for ID=4)
```

My SQL is like so:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT `geometry` as gp FROM geometrytable WHERE `id` = 4) AS TT  
WHERE MBRTouches(TT.gp, geometrytable.`geometry`) = 1;
```

I appreciate I am horribly off the mark in both the above but would really appreciate some guidance on how to tackle this.